# Rabbitmq spring mvc Integration giving error @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, rabbitmq

This is the first time I am doing rabbitmq integration, and i am trying to load applicationContext but every time it gives me same error.

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired 
dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
autowire field: private 
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager 
com.visualpathit.account.service.SecurityServiceImpl
.authenticationManager
; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 
[org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] 
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as 
autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
Autowired(required=true)}
```

### applicationContext.xml

I am referring the Example :
https://dzone.com/articles/rabbitmq-in-cluster
Everything is same i tried the same example throughout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-tegration.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-
integration-amqp.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<!-- Configuration for Component Scan -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.visualpathit.account" />  
<context:property-placeholder 
location="classpath*:rabbitmq.properties"/>
<int:channel id="inputChannel"/>
<int:gateway id="orderGateway" service-
interface="com.visualpathit.account.repository.OrderGateway" default-
request-channel="inputChannel" />  
<int-amqp:channel id="processChannel"
connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
message-driven="true"
queue-name="ha.rabbit.channel" />   
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"  
addresses="${rabbitmq.addresses}" username="${rabbitmq.username}"    
password="${rabbitmq.password}" /> 

<int:splitter id="orderSplitter" input-channel="inputChannel" 
output-channel="processChannel" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="processChannel" 
ref="orderProcessService" method="process" />  
</beans>
```

### SecurityServiceImpl

```
package com.visualpathit.account.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {
/** authenticationManager !*/
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
/** userDetailsService !*/
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

/** Logger creation !*/
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityServiceImpl.class);

@Override
public String findLoggedInUsername() {
    Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                        .getAuthentication().getDetails();
    if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails) {
        return ((UserDetails) userDetails).getUsername();
    }

    return null;
}
 @Override
public void autologin(final String username, final String password) {
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = 
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, 
userDetails.getAuthorities());       
authenticationManager.authenticate 
(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        .setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        logger.debug(String.format("Auto login %s successfully!", 
 username));
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why didn't you put your code here?

Comment: Issue solved for rabbitmq